# Highcharts wrap processData on line charts doesn't draw right data points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My goal is to have a new option on the Y axis of a line chart that allows to toggle between regular Y data series (e.g. [1,2,3]) or the accumulation of the original data series ([1,3,6]).

I started by wrapping the `processData` method as follows

```
(function (H) {

  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.line.prototype, 'processData', function(force) {
    var yData = this.yData;

    for (var i = 1; i < yData.length; i++) {
      yData[i] = yData[i] + yData[i-1];
    };

    //alert(this.yData);

    force.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  });


} (Highcharts));
```

The `this.yData` gives me access to the right data and the rest is pretty straight forward. When plotted I do see the Y-axis limit change as expected, but the data points are still drawn according to their original values (here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oL3LfrLr/)

I suspect it might be some scoping issue but I don't really see what's wrong in the above. Any tips?

Why wrap `processData`?

Not sure to be honest. I'm fairly new to javascript and HighCharts and this is my first extension. I looked at the [Waterfall Series](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/waterfall-series) which does part of what I want and from the source of that I 'guessed' it would either be the `translate` or `processData` method. The latter sounded most promising so I started there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you need to wrap both methods, just like waterfall series. `processData` is necessary for yAxis extremes, and `translate` is responsible for translating point's value to x-y coordinates.

Personally, I would use `generatePoints`, instead of `translate`. Something like this:

```
(function (H) {

  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.line.prototype, 'processData', function (proceed) {
            var yData = this.yData,
            points = this.points;

    if(!this.afterCalc) {
      for (var i = 1; i < yData.length; i++) {
        yData[i] = yData[i] + yData[i-1];
      };
    }
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  });

  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.line.prototype, 'generatePoints', function (proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            var yData = this.yData,
            points = this.data;
    if(!this.afterCalc) {
      for (var i = 1; i < yData.length; i++) {
        points[i].y = yData[i];
      };
      this.afterCalc = true; // calculate this only once
    }
  });


} (Highcharts));
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oL3LfrLr/2/

Comment: Before accepting your answer; could you explain your rationale behind using `generatePoints` over `translate`?

Comment: Just try it and compare the differences ;) In short, `translate` is called for example when resizing browser window, or hiding/showing series in the legend. That means every time `yData` will accumulate vlaues over and over again. Of course, it is possible to avoid that issue, but it is more simple just to wrap `generatePoints()` which is called only when updating series data (or recalculating data).

Comment: Thank you, very valuable input. I couldn't find this from the documentation so was hoping to extract some additional knowledge :)